# Do I have to use weak properties to model parent-children relationships in Core Data?

Tags: core-data, ios8

I know it seems a stupid question, but after modelling the typical master-detail or parent-children relationship in Core Data, I want to create the NSManagedObject subclasses and I realised Core Data code generator is always using strong/retain for the parent properties. Is that right? In a normal object graph that is wrong because we have a retain cycle, but not sure in the Core Data context, because I guess the code generator should generate the code properly. Thanks for suggestions.

After trying to use weak properties in my NSManagedObject subclasses, I receive:

`2016-03-15 11:57:36.921 WWWWW[84639:1153803] CoreData: error: Property 'company' is marked __weak on class 'Package'.  Cannot generate a setter method for it.
2016-03-15 11:57:36.921 WWWW[84639:1153803] -[Package setCompany:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f97917068e0
2016-03-15 11:57:36.933 WWWW[84639:1153803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Package setCompany:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f97917068e0'`

Comment: You're right: CoreData does use strong references, and this does create retain cycles: see "Breaking Strong References Between Objects" in [the CoreData Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/MO_Lifecycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH31-SW1).

Comment: Thanks for helps and the doc.  I didn´t read that doc. I see they mention  refreshObject:mergeChanges: but I don´t see anything about using weak rather than strong/retain. Still not clear to me, but thanks for help.

Comment: It does not work using weak properties. Any help?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that you should use "weak".  Use "strong", but use `refreshObject:mergeChanges` to break the retain cycles (when/if you need to).